# Help with$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)\arctan ^2\left(x\right)\operatorname{arctanh} \left(x^2\right)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}\:\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I would appreciate any help with for proving the following problem
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)\arctan ^2\left(x\right)\operatorname{arctanh} \left(x^2\right)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}\:\mathrm{d}x=\frac{15}{32}\zeta(4)-\frac{3}{8}\ln ^2\left(2\right)\zeta(2)$$
I found this problem on a mathematics group.

I have tried 2 things, using $x=\frac{1}{t}$
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\left(1-t^2\right)\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\arctan \left(t\right)\right)^2\coth \left(t^2\right)}{t\left(1+t^2\right)}\:\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=-\frac{\pi ^2}{8}\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\left(1-t^2\right)\ln \left(\frac{t^2-1}{1+t^2}\right)}{t\left(1+t^2\right)}\:\mathrm{d}t+\frac{\pi }{2}\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\left(1-t^2\right)\arctan \left(t\right)\ln \left(\frac{t^2-1}{1+t^2}\right)}{t\left(1+t^2\right)}\:\mathrm{d}t-\frac{1}{2}\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\left(1-t^2\right)\arctan ^2\left(t\right)\ln \left(\frac{t^2-1}{1+t^2}\right)}{t\left(1+t^2\right)}\:\mathrm{d}t$$
And I think I made the problem harder, the other thing I tried was
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)\arctan ^2\left(x\right)\operatorname{arctanh} \left(x^2\right)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}\:\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=\int _0^1\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)\arctan ^2\left(x\right)\operatorname{arctanh} \left(x^2\right)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}\:\mathrm{d}x+\int _1^{\infty }\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)\arctan ^2\left(x\right)\operatorname{arctanh} \left(x^2\right)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}\:\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=\int _0^1\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)\arctan ^2\left(x\right)\operatorname{arctanh} \left(x^2\right)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}\:\mathrm{d}x+\int _0^1\frac{\left(1-t^2\right)\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\arctan \left(t\right)\right)^2\operatorname{coth} \left(t^2\right)}{t\left(1+t^2\right)}\:\mathrm{d}t$$
And I got stuck again.

Comment: First, you want to consider the real part of the left-hand side. The problem was proposed by Cornel here https://www.facebook.com/photo?fbid=3618177281612377&set=a.222846247812181 where you may also find a solution in the comments. Indeed, it is nice to see more ways to go about such a problem.